# Chart.js horizontal lines cutting vertical ones

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using `react-chartjs-2` to draw a bar chart where my vertical gridlines are of different colour than the horizontal ones. I want the vertical lines to go over horizontal ones but it's the other way around. I wasn't able to find an option that could fix this.

Is there a callback that would swap the order rendering of the lines or something like that?

[image]

Comment: Here is my first try - **not complete!!!** It's off a few pixels and updating doesn't work perfectly (but I think that's a chart.js-problem). When I get it working I write an answer and delete this comment. Just posting if anybody wants a start or can finish it. https://jsbin.com/goxoricusu/edit?js,output      If responsiveness is not necessary it would be very easy. OP, can you confirm you need it responsive?

Comment: This should be good enough, I'll try it out and let you know if it worked out